# GUI Program appears with only one checkbox

Tags: java, eclipse, user-interface, checkbox, jframe

I'm working on a project for school and it has to do with GUI. I'm supposed to make a program that allows for people to choose from three sizes and eight toppings for a pizza. They can choose as many toppings as they want, so I cant do any button groups.

However, I'm running into a recurring problem. As soon as I run the program, The only thing that appears on the screen is a checkbox for the "Mushroom" topping and a text field for the total price. When I check the checkbox, the field reads "$0.00".

```
import java.awt.*;
import javax.swing.*;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;

public class Assignment18 extends JFrame {
private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
private JPanel panel1 = new JPanel();
private JPanel panel2 = new JPanel();
private JLabel message1, message2;
private JTextField results;
private JButton calculate;
private JCheckBox small;
private JCheckBox medium;
private JCheckBox large;
private JCheckBox bacon;
private JCheckBox chicken;
private JCheckBox pineapple;
private JCheckBox anchovies;
private JCheckBox pepperoni;
private JCheckBox spinach;
private JCheckBox sausage;
private JCheckBox mushroom;
private JFrame frame = new JFrame();

public Assignment18() {
    setTitle("Pizza Calculator");
    setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    setLocation(500, 300);

    buildPanel1();
    buildPanel2();

    setLayout(new BorderLayout());
    add(panel1, BorderLayout.NORTH);
    add(panel2, BorderLayout.SOUTH);
    pack();
    setVisible(true);
}

public void buildPanel1() {
    message1 = new JLabel("Pizza Sizes: ");
    message2 = new JLabel("Pizza Toppings(All toppings are $1.50):");

    small = new JCheckBox("Small ($8.00)");
    medium = new JCheckBox("Medium ($9.50)");
    large = new JCheckBox("Large ($11.00)");
    bacon = new JCheckBox("Bacon");
    chicken = new JCheckBox("Chicken");
    pineapple = new JCheckBox("Pineapple");
    anchovies = new JCheckBox("Anchovies");
    pepperoni = new JCheckBox("Pepperoni");
    spinach = new JCheckBox("Spinach");
    sausage = new JCheckBox("Sausage");
    mushroom = new JCheckBox("Mushroom");

    small.addActionListener(new CheckBoxListener());
    medium.addActionListener(new CheckBoxListener());
    large.addActionListener(new CheckBoxListener());
    bacon.addActionListener(new CheckBoxListener());
    chicken.addActionListener(new CheckBoxListener());
    pineapple.addActionListener(new CheckBoxListener());
    anchovies.addActionListener(new CheckBoxListener());
    pepperoni.addActionListener(new CheckBoxListener());
    spinach.addActionListener(new CheckBoxListener());
    sausage.addActionListener(new CheckBoxListener());
    mushroom.addActionListener(new CheckBoxListener());

    panel1 = new JPanel();
    panel1.setLayout(new BorderLayout(6, 3));
    panel1.add(message1);
    panel1.add(small);
    panel1.add(medium);
    panel1.add(large);
    panel1.add(message2);
    panel1.add(bacon);
    panel1.add(chicken);
    panel1.add(pineapple);
    panel1.add(anchovies);
    panel1.add(pepperoni);
    panel1.add(spinach);
    panel1.add(sausage);
    panel1.add(mushroom);
    frame.add(panel1);
}

public void buildPanel2() {
    calculate = new JButton("Calculate Pizza Cost");
    calculate.addActionListener(new CheckBoxListener());
    results = new JTextField();
    results.setEditable(false);

    panel2 = new JPanel();
    panel2.setLayout(new BorderLayout(1, 2));
    panel2.add(calculate);
    panel2.add(results);
    frame.add(panel2);
}

private class CheckBoxListener implements ActionListener {
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
        double size1 = 8.0;
        double size2 = 9.5;
        double size3 = 11.0;
        double topping = 1.5;
        double result = 0;
        if (small.isSelected() && bacon.isSelected())
            result = size1 + topping;
        else if (small.isSelected() && chicken.isSelected())
            result = size1 + topping;
        else if (small.isSelected() && pineapple.isSelected())
            result = size1 + topping;
        else if (small.isSelected() && anchovies.isSelected())
            result = size1 + topping;
        else if (small.isSelected() && sausage.isSelected())
            result = size1 + topping;
        else if (small.isSelected() && pepperoni.isSelected())
            result = size1 + topping;
        else if (small.isSelected() && spinach.isSelected())
            result = size1 + topping;
        else if (small.isSelected() && mushroom.isSelected())
            result = size1 + topping;
        else if (medium.isSelected() && bacon.isSelected())
            result = size2 + topping;
        else if (medium.isSelected() && chicken.isSelected())
            result = size2 + topping;
        else if (medium.isSelected() && pineapple.isSelected())
            result = size2 + topping;
        else if (medium.isSelected() && anchovies.isSelected())
            result = size2 + topping;
        else if (medium.isSelected() && sausage.isSelected())
            result = size2 + topping;
        else if (medium.isSelected() && pepperoni.isSelected())
            result = size2 + topping;
        else if (medium.isSelected() && spinach.isSelected())
            result = size2 + topping;
        else if (medium.isSelected() && mushroom.isSelected())
            result = size2 + topping;
        else if (large.isSelected() && bacon.isSelected())
            result = size3 + topping;
        else if (large.isSelected() && chicken.isSelected())
            result = size3 + topping;
        else if (large.isSelected() && pineapple.isSelected())
            result = size3 * topping;
        else if (large.isSelected() && anchovies.isSelected())
            result = size3 + topping;
        else if (large.isSelected() && sausage.isSelected())
            result = size3 + topping;
        else if (large.isSelected() && pepperoni.isSelected())
            result = size3 + topping;
        else if (large.isSelected() && spinach.isSelected())
            result = size3 + topping;
        else if (large.isSelected() && mushroom.isSelected())
            result = size3 + topping;
        results.setText(String.format("$%,.2f", result));
    }
}
public static void main(String[] args) {
    Assignment18 pizza = new Assignment18();
}
}
```

Thank you!

Comment: That's the craziest action listener I've ever seen. You have 24 separate if statements, what happens if the first statement resolves to true? You then still have to run through 23 more checks even though they're all false. Have you heard of the `else if` or `else` keywords?

Comment: Oops, guess that was a pretty big thing to miss... Thanks!

Comment: small, medium, and large should probably be radio buttons?  and you are "adding" your panels twice.  Once in build methods, once in constructor.

Comment: Oh, didn't even think of that. Thank you ^ _ ^

Comment: also you only need one listener on the calculate button. (And I would be an unhappy customer if the per topping price addition was the same for all sizes of pizza)

Comment: Thanks again! And yeah, haha, I would be too. The place is out of business in my imagination ^^